# Chart JS chart not rendering in ArcGIS popup when using navigation arrows

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, chart

I'm putting a chart in the popup of my points. On the initial click, the popups display the chart and if I use the forward navigation arrow on the popup, the next chart renders. However, if I use the back arrow the chart will not render again. The method that generates the charts doesn't seem to be firing the second time.

My code is below. Popup:

```
            popupTemplate: {
            title: "{Location}",
            content: [{
                type: "text",
                text: "Sample Location: {Type} </br> Survey: {Survey} </br> {Location:getSurveyInfo} <div id='chartDiv'><canvas id='chartArea'>{Location:createChart}</canvas></div>"
            },
            {
                type: "attachments"
            }]
        }
```

Chart:

```
    createChart = function (location) {
    var date = new Date();
    var chartArea = "chartArea";
    var sub = location.substring(0, 2);

    getData(date.getFullYear(), [[location]], function (data) {
        var maxScale = Math.max(...data[0].tData);
        var colors = [["#34eb58", "#0000ff"]];
        var chartData = buildChartData(name, maxScale, data, colors, null);
        var ctx = document.getElementById(chartArea);
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, chartData);

    }, getChartDataError)



}
```

Answer (score 2):

To run code every time the popup changes (even for prev/next arrow button clicks), use the "watch" functionality to watch the ["selectedFeature" property of the Popup](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Popup.html#selectedFeature):

```
createChart = function (graphic) {
    // use "graphic.attributes" in this function to get the attributes of the clicked feature.
    // you may need to wrap your code in a setTimeout() function here to wait for the popup to open before you modify the DOM inside the Popup.
    ...
}
view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", createChart);
```

Comment: Attempting to do this moves my popup to the upper left corner and then doesn't allow me to click anything on the map after.

Comment: @DangerFox for that I think you need to wrap your code in the createChart function with the "setTimeout()" - see my comment in the example code:     // you may need to wrap your code in a setTimeout() function here to wait for the popup to open before you modify the DOM inside the Popup.

Comment: When I wrap it in that it still gives the same error and it also tells me that graphic is undefined. I changed my call in the template to just be {createChart}